# What is the equivalent of Linux's ldd on windows?

Tags: windows, linker, shared-libraries, ldd, dependency-walker

What is the equivalent of Linux's `ldd` on Windows?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here is Dependency Walker.

http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: does anything like ldd exist, for command line only?  Looking for something I can use from a prompt.  Prefer a small light command, preferably without extra DLLs.

Comment: It appears that that has a command line interface: http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm

Comment: Syntax looks something like this:
depends.exe /c /oc:dependencies.csv /ot:dependencies.txt mydll.dll

Comment: Dependency Walker works well, but is a jarring change from the simplicity of ldd (especially if you're used to scripting a tool consume its output and do, say, packaging tasks automatically with it).

Comment: Crashes on Windows 10.

Answer (score 69):

The `dumpbin` command can be useful for many things, although in this case dependency walker is probably a little more verbose.

```
dumpbin /dependents some.dll
```

Example output:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools>dumpbin /dependents StanPolicy.dll
>
> Dump of file StanPolicy.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> Image has the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> mscoree.dll
> ```
>
> Summary
>
> ```
>     2000 .reloc
>     2000 .rsrc
>    1E000 .text
> ```

Comment: This is the best option if you have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 43):

or the GNU tool :

```
i586-mingw32msvc-objdump -p  *.exe    | grep 'DLL Name:'
```

Comment: Can objdump be used to display the full path? I need something recursively and this requires fullpath for each dependant DLL

Comment: objdump only shows you what the file contains. It does not attempt to do any path lookup like `ldd` does.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using `wine` and not real Windows, you can use `WINEDEBUG=+loaddll wine <program>`.

Comment: Developing against Wine to target Windows struck me as so strange an idea I had to give it a try (I primarily target Linux)... and actually it is working out *far* smoother than I expected for prototyping. Very, very cool.

Comment: Re: development using Wine instead of Windows: note that what works in Wine won't necessarily work on real Windows. I learned this when I forgot to call `GdiplusStartup`, and GDI+ worked without problems in Wine, while on Windows it didn't. I only noticed this mistake after having debugged the program in Wine, trying next to run it in Windows.

Comment: I test things on Wine all the time, just to avoid restarting and changing OS. However, it's good practice before a major release--or any time you've done something that feels even a little suspicious--to try it out on Windows native as well.

Answer (score 13):

Newer versions of Git on Windows come packaged with something called *Git BASH*, which emulates many useful Unix commands including ldd.

It appears that it reports only libraries that can be found. So you can use this to get an overview of where the used libraries are located, but not which are missing.

Answer (score 10):

There is now an `ldd` in Cygwin. If you have a very old Cygwin version, you will have to use `cygcheck`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not very accurate

Comment: Still not very accurate in 2023 - when I run it over and over again on an MSYS2/UCRT executable developed for a customer (that doesn't change at all...), I'll usually get something between 35 and 40 DLLs listed.  Every now and then I even get the correct 41 dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the Windows Developer way to do this is to use `dumpbin /dependents source.exe`. If you have Visual Studio installed you can find it here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe`.

Comment: Too bad this doesn't show where the dependents are found so you can precisely see which ones are actually used at runtime :(.

Comment: @rubenvb Process Explorer from SysInternals MS suite has lower-pane view of all DLLs a binary loads including their paths and symbol/dll search.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 10 you can use Dependencies - An open-source modern Dependency Walker

https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 5):

For windows 10, with visual studio 2017, I go in the search bar of windows and type:

"developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" ( a special cmd.exe for Visual studio developer)

This allows to get access to DUMPBIN that should be used with the /IMPORTS tag. For example, in the correct directory:

DUMPBIN /IMPORTS yourfile.exe (others extension may work too)

For me, this list the DLL and the functions used.

Alternatively, you can use the tag \ALL that is much more verbose.

see the microsoft explanation of DUMPBIN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/imports-dumpbin?view=vs-2019

[Example ( with only a part) of the content sended back by the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnGfT.png)

Comment: the complete example like : `dumpbin /imports *.dll | find /i ".dll"`

Comment: Great addition to old answers!

Comment: This answer could be a comment to the prior answers, just noting that some users might prefer to sue the developer command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I use the cmder as terminal for most things (and not powershell/pwsh). For cmder you can simply type "ldd my_executable.exe" and you will see the expected output.

Link to download cmder: https://cmder.net/

Comment: That is `ldd` bundled with git bash, which was already mentioned in previous answers.