# Using wxwidgets to create a gui

Tags: python

I need to create a cross platform GUI mainly targetting Windows and Linux. I finally decided that I would use the wxWidgets library to get it done since it has a less restrictive license and has a python binding. However I just wanted to know if I would have to install wxPython on every computer that needs to run my GUI. Because I really cant ask the user to go to the site and install wxPython in order to get my software working. Is there any way around this? IS there any other good cross platform GUI toolkit apart from Java,Qt and wxWidgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/) explains how to use wxPython together with pyinstaller, allowing you to build an .exe file for Windows.

On linux you can use .deb files and add python-wxgtk2.8 to the dependencies; If a user doesn't use .deb files, he should probably know how to install wxPython :)

Answer (score 0):

> However I just wanted to know if I would have to install wxPython on every computer that needs to run my GUI.

If you don't want to manually install wxPython on each computer, you'd have to include all of the wxPython library with your distribution (i.e. the contents of the `wx` directory which is probably somewhere in `site-packages` or `dist-packages`), and any other libraries they depend on which aren't typically installed by default.

On Linux, you might just be able to use `ldd` on wxPython's `.pyd` files to find out what they depend on, and you can do [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993673/what-is-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-ldd-on-windows) for Windows.

If it's loading stuff via `dlopen(3)` or the Windows equivalent, it's a bit more complicated. You might have to try it, wait to see what missing libs it complains about, and add those to the distro.