# cxFreeze issues with OpenCV - video doesn't play

Tags: python, opencv, cx-freeze

When I use cx_Frezze to create an `exe` for the below OpenCV code it works as expected:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,50,70),-1)

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But, when I try to do the same thing with the simple code below, the video is not displayed. Basically, nothing happens. No error message, no crash... nothing. But, no video.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('some_video.wmv')

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except:
    pass
```

The `setup.py` code is the same for both, except for the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Add `print` statements to your code for debugging:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('some_video.wmv')
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print('VideoCapture not opened')
        exit(1)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print('frame is empty')
            break

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except:
    pass
```

If `VideoCapture` is not opened or frame is empty then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116576/2286337).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. I checked, as you suggested; it seems VideoCapture not opened. I check your other answer, and FFMPEG is Yes. My concern is that when I run the python file this code works as expected. I only have the problem after I create the exe file with cx_Freeze. Usually, when cx_Freeze is missing some files, it will let me know, so if FFMPEG was missing , I would get an error. But, I am not getting any error.

Comment: @JoeT.Boka Use [dependency walker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993677/2286337) to find out to which libraries the executable is linking.